# Check if a functon runs as an imported module

Tags: python

Is possible to check within a function if the given function runs within the script or runs as an imported module in another script?

For example:

```
def func():
    if func was imported:
        do this
    else: # it runs within the script
        do that
```

Comment: try `if __name__=='__main__'` inside function

Comment: This seems a dubious question. Why do you need this? See [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @GhostOps no, that's nothing to do with it.

Comment: @PeterWood why do you think it is an XY Problem? The answers are what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rewrite your function like this:

```py
def func():
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        print("I'm running within this script.")
    else:
        print("I was imported to another script.")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    func()
```

If you run the current script, you'll get the following output:

```
./test.py
>>> I'm running within this script.
```

If you run `from test import func; func()` you'll get the following:

```
>>> I was imported to another script.
```

Answer (score 0):

Every module has a `__name__`, if it is imported it will be equal to the name of the module, else it will be `'__main__'` if it is in the script you run

```
def func():
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        # Do this
    else:
        # Do that
```